# How do I connect to a PostGres 14 server installed via Homebrew on Mac OS Big Sur?

Tags: postgresql, psql, homebrew

I installed PostGreSQL 14 via Homebrew.  I seem to be able to restart my local server ...

```
$ brew services restart postgresql@14
Stopping `postgresql@14`... (might take a while)
==> Successfully stopped `postgresql@14` (label: homebrew.mxcl.postgresql@14)
==> Successfully started `postgresql@14` (label: homebrew.mxcl.postgresql@14)
```

but whenever I try and connect, I repeatedly get this error

```
$ psql -Upostgres
psql: error: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?
```

What is the proper way to connect via psql to PostGres 14 on Mac OS Big Sur?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably getting a 'read the docs' downvote, but I'll jump in as we've all been there.

Your error is simple. There needs to be a space between the `-U` flag and the username.

If this is a vanilla install just typing `psql` should get you access to the database.

[psql doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html)